# PySpark MLLib Zeppelin Logistic Regression Metrics error: AssertionError: dimension mismatch

Tags: pyspark, logistic-regression, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to run a logistic regression in Pyspark with MLLib. The model runs but I am unable to get out any metrics.

My data is in csv format, which I convert as follows:

```
def load(prefix):
    lines = spark.read.text(prefix).rdd
    parts = lines.map(lambda row: row.value.split(","))
    ratingsRDD = parts.map(lambda p: Row(pct = str(p[0]), date = str(p[1]), res_burg_label=int(p[2]), com_burg=int(p[3]), res_burg=int(p[4]), mvl=int(p[5]), street_rob=int(p[6])))
    return spark.createDataFrame(ratingsRDD).cache()

training = load("csv")

df = training.select('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
temp = df.rdd.map(lambda line:LabeledPoint(line[0],[line[1:]]))
(trainingData, testData) = temp.randomSplit([0.7, 0.3])

model = LogisticRegressionWithSGD.train(trainingData)

from pyspark.mllib.evaluation import MulticlassMetrics
predictions = model.predict(testData.map(lambda x: x.features))
labelsAndPredictions = testData.map(lambda lp: lp.label).zip(predictions)
```

Everything works fine until here. I have also used this part as input for a Random Forest, which worked fine. However, when using this for Logistic Regression or Naive Bayes, I am having issues with the metrics. I'm wondering if this is related to the format since the error is regarding a dimension issue...

As soon as I try to access the following metrics, I'm getting an error:

```
from pyspark.mllib.evaluation import BinaryClassificationMetrics
metrics = BinaryClassificationMetrics(labelsAndPredictions)
print("Area under PR = %s" % metrics.areaUnderPR)
```

The error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-2645257958953635503.py", line 367, in <module>
    raise Exception(traceback.format_exc())
Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-2645257958953635503.py", line 360, in <module>
    exec(code, _zcUserQueryNameSpace)
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/mllib/evaluation.py", line 72, in areaUnderPR
    return self.call("areaUnderPR")
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/mllib/common.py", line 146, in call
    return callJavaFunc(self._sc, getattr(self._java_model, name), *a)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/mllib/common.py", line 123, in callJavaFunc
    return _java2py(sc, func(*args))
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o2656.areaUnderPR.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 770.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 770.0 (TID 831, ip-172-31-82-213.ec2.internal, executor 1): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/zeppelin/appcache/application_1521221169368_0001/container_1521221169368_0001_01_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 177, in main
    process()
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/zeppelin/appcache/application_1521221169368_0001/container_1521221169368_0001_01_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 172, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/zeppelin/appcache/application_1521221169368_0001/container_1521221169368_0001_01_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 220, in dump_stream
    self.serializer.dump_stream(self._batched(iterator), stream)
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/zeppelin/appcache/application_1521221169368_0001/container_1521221169368_0001_01_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 138, in dump_stream
    for obj in iterator:
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/zeppelin/appcache/application_1521221169368_0001/container_1521221169368_0001_01_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 209, in _batched
    for item in iterator:
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/mllib/classification.py", line 202, in <lambda>
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/zeppelin/appcache/application_1521221169368_0001/container_1521221169368_0001_01_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/mllib/classification.py", line 206, in predict
    margin = self.weights.dot(x) + self._intercept
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/zeppelin/appcache/application_1521221169368_0001/container_1521221169368_0001_01_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/mllib/linalg/__init__.py", line 372, in dot
    assert len(self) == _vector_size(other), "dimension mismatch"
AssertionError: dimension mismatch
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ZippedPartitionsRDD2.compute(ZippedPartitionsRDD.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1708)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1696)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1695)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1695)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:855)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:855)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:855)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1923)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1878)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1867)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:671)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2029)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2050)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2069)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2094)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:936)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:935)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.BinaryClassificationMetrics.x$4$lzycompute(BinaryClassificationMetrics.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.BinaryClassificationMetrics.x$4(BinaryClassificationMetrics.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.BinaryClassificationMetrics.confusions$lzycompute(BinaryClassificationMetrics.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.BinaryClassificationMetrics.confusions(BinaryClassificationMetrics.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.BinaryClassificationMetrics.createCurve(BinaryClassificationMetrics.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.BinaryClassificationMetrics.pr(BinaryClassificationMetrics.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.BinaryClassificationMetrics.areaUnderPR(BinaryClassificationMetrics.scala:117)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/zeppelin/appcache/application_1521221169368_0001/container_1521221169368_0001_01_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 177, in main
    process()
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/zeppelin/appcache/application_1521221169368_0001/container_1521221169368_0001_01_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 172, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/zeppelin/appcache/application_1521221169368_0001/container_1521221169368_0001_01_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 220, in dump_stream
    self.serializer.dump_stream(self._batched(iterator), stream)
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/zeppelin/appcache/application_1521221169368_0001/container_1521221169368_0001_01_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 138, in dump_stream
    for obj in iterator:
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/zeppelin/appcache/application_1521221169368_0001/container_1521221169368_0001_01_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 209, in _batched
    for item in iterator:
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/mllib/classification.py", line 202, in <lambda>
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/zeppelin/appcache/application_1521221169368_0001/container_1521221169368_0001_01_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/mllib/classification.py", line 206, in predict
    margin = self.weights.dot(x) + self._intercept
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/zeppelin/appcache/application_1521221169368_0001/container_1521221169368_0001_01_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/mllib/linalg/__init__.py", line 372, in dot
    assert len(self) == _vector_size(other), "dimension mismatch"
AssertionError: dimension mismatch
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ZippedPartitionsRDD2.compute(ZippedPartitionsRDD.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the error is in predicting on the training data using the model: `model.predict(testData.map(lambda x: x.features))` due to mismatch in the dimensions of `testData.map(lambda x: x.features)` and the `trainingData`, which should have been same.

Since RDDs have lazy operations, you are encountering it while you call the MulticlassMetrics.

Comment: I have the same issue using: from pyspark.mllib.evaluation import BinaryClassificationMetrics
metrics = BinaryClassificationMetrics(labelsAndPredictions) print("Area under PR = %s" % metrics.areaUnderPR)

Comment: This is strange. Try checking the dimensions of the weights in the trained model: `model ` It should be accessible by: `model.weights`